# How to copy tab-contained text from Excel without quotes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, libreoffice-calc

I've noticed that a cell that contains a *tab* is copied with quotes embedded. I'm looking for copying such kind of a cell without the quotes.

---

### Illustrative Example

I've 5 cells; A1, A2, A3, A4, and A5. The formulas for them are:

[image]

This is how they would look like on Excel:

[image]

The formulas are set like that to make the expected result when copying cells to a text editor be like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, this is what I get:

[image]

The problem is with **quotes**. What I need is copying those cells without the quotes.

Comment: I presume that Find/Replace for `"tab` and `1"` is an unacceptable solution given your real data? Or is this a general annoyance question and not specific to a particular file?

Comment: Yes, this isn't a specific particular situation question, it's a general annoyance question. What I need to get to is to copy cells without the double quotes. Find/Replace for `"tab` and `1"` isn't a solution because the mentioned situation is just for illustrative purposes, and I need a solution embedded within Excel so that I could finish my objectives as few steps as possible without the double quotes appearing with the copied text.

Comment: Then the VBA I submitted set to a keyboard command will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a VBA solution? This will copy all the select from the top left selected cell to the bottom right selected cell. If you select incongruous cells, this code will collected everything in between the top left and bottom right anyway. You can change that, of course. It was just easier this way. It puts tabs between the columns and line breaks between the rows.

```
Sub CopyText()

    Dim obj As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim rTL, rBR, cTL, cBR

    rTL = Selection.Cells(1, 1).Row
    cTL = Selection.Cells(1, 1).Column

    For Each rng In Selection.Cells
        If rng.Row < rTL Then rTL = rng.Row
        If rng.Column < cTL Then cTL = rng.Column
        If rng.Row > rBR Then rBR = rng.Row
        If rng.Column > cBR Then cBR = rng.Column
    Next

    For r = rTL To rBR
        For c = cTL To cBR
            s = s & Cells(r, c).Value
            If c < cBR Then s = s & Chr(9)
        Next
        If r < rBR Then s = s & vbNewLine
    Next

    Set obj = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    obj.SetText s
    obj.PutInClipboard
    Set obj = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you're wondering about this part:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
```

... that's just the late-binding version of `Set obj = New DataObject` so you don't have to add any references in VBA.